# Questions concerning Trace Theorem (Evans - PDE)

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, chain-rule

A proof of this theorem can be found in Evans (p.272, 2nd Ed.). This question addresses persons who are familiar with the proof, since I have not been able to formulate a question that generalizes my problem.

> **THEOREM 1** (Trace Theorem)**.** Assume $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Then there exists a bounded linear operator $$T : W^{1,p}(U) \rightarrow L^p(\partial U)$$ such that
>
> $\quad$(i) $Tu=u|_{\partial U}$ if $u \in W^{1,p}(U) \cap C(\bar{U})$
>
> and
>
> $\quad$(ii) $$\|Tu\|_{L^p(\partial U)} \le C \|  u\|_{W^{1,p} (U)},$$ for each $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$, with the constant $C$ depending only on $p$ and $U$.

The problem lies in the second part (2.) of the proof.

> Applying estimate (1) and changing variables, we obtain the bound
>   $$
> \int_\Gamma |u|^p dS \leq C \int_U |u|^p + |Du|^p dx.
> $$

Let $\Gamma$ denote the portion of the boundary of $U$ and let $\Gamma' = \Phi(\Gamma)$ the straightened portion of the boundary.

Using the change of variables formula we calculate
$$
\int_\Gamma |u|^p dS = \int_{\Gamma'} |u \circ \Phi|^p dS' 
\leq \int_{\Phi(U)} |u \circ \Phi|^p + |D(u \circ \Phi)|^p dx
$$

The first part can be transformed back as usual but we don't know how to transform the second part involving $D(u \circ \Phi)$.

Comment: You have $D(u \circ \Phi) = (Du(\Phi) )D\Phi$. Since the boundary is nice there is some uniform control on $D\Phi$.

Comment: I agree that what you say is valid but I don't see how this is useful.

Comment: Small typo in (ii):  $U$ on the right inside the norm should be $u$.